# Autodesk Forge - are Units always the same?

Tags: autodesk-forge

In the Autodesk Forge system, when you do a Post jobs to create an svf file and then eventually pull down the [properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/), the units that are returned are as follows - mass = g, volume = mm^3, area = mm^2, etc

Are those units always the same? For larger systems, are they returned in kg, m^3, m^2?

Is there a way to ask for specific units - like kg, m^3, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the same unit that’s specific to the properties of a model - take the sample data from our website and note the difference in units:

```
 "File Properties": {
            "Author": "ADSK",
            "Creation Date": "2012-Jul-09 20:18:35",
            "Original System": "Autodesk Inventor 2017",
            "Part Number": "Pillar"
          },
          "Mass Properties": {
            "Area": "7000 millimeter^2",
            "Volume": "25000 millimeter^3"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "objectid": 6,
        "name": "Cylinder",
        "externalId": "2Iu0zG8ViUOsqUzhb4TUiA",
        "properties": {
          "Mass:": "0.012 gram",
          "Name": "Cylinder"
        }
      }
```

Comment: But is the mass always given in grams or is it sometimes given in kg? Is the area always given in mm^2 or is it sometimes given in m^2?

Comment: Can't guarantee they are always the same - but since they always come explicitly with units better to use libraries like [this](https://github.com/gentooboontoo/js-quantities) and [this](https://github.com/atulmish/UnitConversion) to convert them to the same unit that suits you needs best